# Put iframe in window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, backbone.js

I have one button in `html` template of text! plugin :

```
<input type="button" id="_print" value="Print">
<iframe name="theFrame"></iframe>
```

And this is the click event in my view of backbone :

```
  checkOut : function(){
        var params = [
            'height='+screen.height,
            'width='+screen.width,
            'fullscreen=yes'
        ].join(',');

        var popup = window.open('urlishere','theFrame', params);
        popup.moveTo(0,0);
  }
```

Is it possible to use window.open to open `iframe`?

Comment: So, the button will open the URL of the `iframe` in a new window?  Is that right?

Comment: I want that, but what I have tried, it just open url in iframe, and the window is not popup.

Comment: How is the current iframe working ? there is no source ?

Comment: @Ani: I suppose the url that I put in window.open is the iframe's source.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't see the tag backbone. But if it works for you, here are my 2 cents

For print to work: http://jsfiddle.net/zyGfL/1/

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" id="_print" value="Print" onclick="checkout()">
 <iframe name="theFrame"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
 function checkout(){
    var params = [
        'height='+screen.height,
        'width='+screen.width,
        'fullscreen=yes'
    ].join(',');

    var popup = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","_blank", params);

  }
```

I am not sure how your Iframe is working currently. But for the print button to work, you have to do something like this.

Comment: There's no problem with the button click Ani.